# Solaris disk I/O spike... which monitoring tools do I need?

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, monitoring, solaris, hard-drive

My Solaris 10 websever / database server disk io keeps spiking at intermittent times.

Using `iostat -xtc 5` the reads / sec will jump from 3.0 to 1450.0 and %busy will jump to 98%

The apache access log doesn't indicate anything out of the ordinary. In other words, requests aren't any higher than usual.

`top` doesn't generate anything useful. The cpu usage is fine with mysql using about 20% and nothing else to speak of really.

What monitoring tool should I be using to see what process is using excessive disk I/O? or if there are any other suggestions I'm all ears.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [dtrace](http://www.sun.com/bigadmin/content/dtrace/index.jsp). Try the [dtrace toolkit](http://www.solarisinternals.com/wiki/index.php/DTraceToolkit), it comes with lots of scripts and howto files.

[Here's a nice presentation, and a few one-liners you may find useful.](http://www.nbl.fi/~nbl97/solaris/dtrace/index.html)

```
Files Opened by process
$ dtrace -qn 'syscall::open*:entry{ printf("%s %s\n",execname,copyinstr(arg0)); }'

Read Bytes by process
$ dtrace -n 'sysinfo:::readch{ @[execname] = sum(arg0);}'

Write Bytes by process
$ dtrace -n 'sysinfo:::writech{ @[execname] = sum(arg0);}'
```